# Scroll long text on OLED display

Tags: arduino

How to scroll a long text on an 128x64 OLED display
am using Adafruit_SSD1306 driver
This code only displays "This" because the text is too large to fit on the display, but when i scroll the text only "This" is scrolling not the rest of the text

```
display.setTextSize(5);
display.setTextColor(WHITE);
display.setCursor(0,16);
display.clearDisplay();
display.print("This is a long long text");
display.display();
delay(1); 
display.startscrollleft(0x00, 0x0F);
```

Comment: Scrolling will scroll what is displayed on the screen. The rest of your text isn't.

Comment: yes i see that, but how can i get long text to scroll ?

Comment: I don't really know. I don't think you can do that with the SSD1306 library, and i'm unsure the uno (if that's the one you're using) has enough memory to store all of the rendered text.

Answer (score 4):

Scroll and wrap around long text lines on a ssd1306 display:

This code is from YT which does this beautifully. My version below works on a ssd1306 128x64 display. Temporary text strings for demo purpose only.
It displays 5 lines, the first is stationary. All the remaining scroll. The next line is text size "2". The others are size "1".

```
/* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTYPuDMPva8
   Set the appropriate screen size in the Adafruit_SSD1306.h by uncommenting
   one of the two following lines.

   //#define SSD1306_128_64 ///< DEPRECTAED: old way to specify 128x64 screen
   //#define SSD1306_128_32 ///< DEPRECATED: old way to specify 128x32 screen
*/

   #include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
   #include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

   Adafruit_SSD1306 display(4);

   char message[]="297M LstWyPt, 345M StPt, rec#89";
   int x, minX;

  void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setTextWrap(false);
  x = display.width();
  minX = -12 * strlen(message);  // 12 = 6 pixels/character * text size 2
  }

  void loop(){
       
   display.clearDisplay();
   display.setCursor(0,0);
   display.setTextSize(1);
   display.print("Sat:13  03:56:32  67%");// GPS # Satellites, Time, % Batt chg
   display.setTextSize(2);
   display.setCursor(x,10);
   display.print(message);
   display.setCursor(x,28);
   display.setTextSize(1);
   display.print("Press #1 New StPt, 2 RecWayPt, Cur 32.567, -102.456");
   display.setCursor(x,38);
   display.setTextSize(1);
   display.print("Press #1 New StPt, 2 RecWayPt, Cur 32.567, -102.456");
   display.setCursor(x,48);
   display.setTextSize(1);
   display.print("Press #1 New StPt, 2 RecWayPt, Cur 32.567, -102.456");
   display.display();
   x=x-8; // scroll speed, make more positive to slow down the scroll
   if(x < minX) x= display.width();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by either:

1. Continuously redrawing the entire frame buffer, or
2. Shifting the framebuffer contents left and rendering a column worth of text (just a fraction of a character) on the right.

The SSD1306 chip provides commands to enable both continuous scrolling and 1 pixel scroll. For our purpose of scrolling long text, the continuous scroll is not useful, as we want to scroll exactly one pixel. Therefore, we need to use the 1 pixel scroll command. The commands take the same parameters, except for the first opcode byte. For some reason in the widely circulated (and pretty old) datasheet online, the 1 pixel scroll command is missing, but it is there in HW.

```
#define CMD_CONTINUOUS_SCROLL_H_RIGHT       0x26
#define CMD_CONTINUOUS_SCROLL_H_LEFT        0x27
#define CMD_ONE_COLUMN_SCROLL_H_RIGHT       0x2C
#define CMD_ONE_COLUMN_SCROLL_H_LEFT        0x2D
```

Use the latter two.

Answer (score 0):

As i have been dealing with my 64x48 oled display for several days, the ssd1306 comes with a 128x64 RAM, and supports scrolling cyclically, as the panel you are using, there is no spare RAM for buffering new data to the RAM spaces outside the active area, so i think you can follow this: put one column, scroll one column(or multiple columns) and wait for action done by delay method, put next column(s)...

Good Luck!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Um - this is an answer, not a question!